# Is 77 ななじゅうなな or しちじゅうしち here?

Tags: numbers, multiple-readings

One of the sentences I found in an online paper and put into my Anki deck is

77年前【ねんまえ】、原爆【げんばく】はなぜ長崎【ながさき】に落【お】とされたのか？

*Why was the atomic bomb dropped on Nagasaki 77 years ago?*

How is 77 read?

If I google ななじゅうなな, I get "About 1.730.000.000 results"

and Tae Kim says,  "七十七 （ななじゅうなな）= 77"

http://www.guidetojapanese.org/numbers.html

However, a google search for しちじゅうしち produces "About 1.010.000.000 results"

and there is a bank called

株式会社七十七銀行（しちじゅうしちぎんこう、英: The 77 Bank, Ltd.）

[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/七十七銀行](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%83%E5%8D%81%E4%B8%83%E9%8A%80%E8%A1%8C)

Can I just pick my favorite? Does it matter?

Comment: This is unrelated to your question but are you European? In most English-speaking areas, the comma and dot with numbers are reversed. 1.730 is a decimal (one point seven hundred and thirty), while 1,730 is a number in the thousands (one thousand seven hundred and thirty). I believe this is also true in Japan.

Comment: I am googling in Germany and just copied and pasted from the google result. You are quite right; I should have changed it to "1,730,000,000" instead.

Comment: I think I found an example of how a Japanese text contains a comma instead of a decimal: 車【くるま】で通【かよ】っていたころは2,5キロほどの距離【きょり】でも20分【にじゅっぷん】近【ちか】くかかっていたが、今【いま】は以前【いぜん】の半分【はんぶん】の約【やく】10分【じゅっぷん】

When he used to commute by car, it took him nearly 20 minutes for a distance of 2.5 km, but now it takes about 10 minutes, half the time before.

https://www.fnn.jp/articles/-/436038

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine. See the [Wikipedia/77](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/77):

> 77（七十七、ななじゅうなな、ななじゅうしち、しちじゅうしち、ななそじあまりななつ）

Except ななそじあまりななつ, the other three could be used, but ななじゅうなな is the most common.

しち is more for specific combinations (7月, 7時, etc.) or sounds a little dated.

Comment: I did not think to look up "77" on wikipedia! :D Thank you for the idea!